# How to fit two full baths in this space?

Tags: bathroom, construction, design, building, architecture

I’m looking for any layout ideas about how to fit two full bathrooms in the space in this picture. One entering from the bedroom and one from the hallway. A few design things. We want the hallway bathroom to be as large as possible and incorporate the window and a double vanity if possible. The bathroom for the bedroom can be tiny but still needs at least a shower, sink and toilet. The doors can be located anywhere on the walls. Is there a way to pull that off? All the plans we can come up with incorporating the window and the double vanity don’t leave enough space for the full bathroom off the bedroom. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: The problem with having the window in the 'main' bathroom is that leaves only the lower-left corner for the 'en-suite'. This then leads to you having to waste a significant amount of floor space on a passageway between the hallway and the main bathroom. You don't have space to waste here, so I'd recommend you drop the requirement of the window in the main bathroom.

Comment: Consider a frosted and high internal window between bathrooms if what you are after is natural light. Or one of those roof-tube "skylights" - ventilation-wise, use a fan or HRV.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could come up with your criteria. **I like your design much better**.

My drawing is very roughly to scale- I didn't spend too much time- I just wanted to see if there was a way to fit all that in there.

Trying to get that window to be in the hall bath just wastes too much space- basically creating a hallway.

[image]